# I wants to remove list of character string from the original string in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to remove "LIMITED", "LTD", "CORPORATION", "GMBH", "AG", "SDN", "BHD", "INC" string from my Customer_Name variable.
I tried with compress function in SAS like 
Customer_Name1=compress(Customer_Name, 'LIMITED', 'LTD', 'GMBH');

But i am getting error -

> The COMPRESS function call has too many arguments.

Please suggest way to solve it.

Comment: Compress removes characters, not words. Look at TRANWRD().

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression to perform this.  Store the words to be removed in a macro variable, then use `call prxchange` to search within name and remove them.  The words are separated by `|`, which signifies `or` in regular expression language.

```
%let vals = LIMITED|LTD|CORPORATION|GMBH|AG|SDN|BHD|INC;

data have;
input name $20.;
datalines;
a ltd
b limited
c corporation
d corp
e gmbh
f test
g ag
i sdn
j bhd
aggregate ag
income inc
;
run;

data want;
set have;
regex = prxparse("s/\b(&vals.)\b//i"); /* /b signifies a word boundary, so it will remove the whole words only */
call prxchange(regex,-1,name);
drop regex;
run;
```